# triplet in tuplet

Tags: theory, sheet-music, tuplet

From this Tuplet [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols):   A triplet: “three notes played in the normal duration of four”.  But I could not verify this on couple of the music sheets and from entering notes using flat.io site.

Then I found another [explanation](https://www.liveabout.com/triplet-definition-2701825): “A triplet group’s total duration is equal to two of the original note-values contained within.”  This one I was able to verify.

So was the info from wikipedia wrong?

Comment: Hae you checked back at Wiki? It doesn't say what you say it says.

Comment: If you look carefully, your first item is a "2-beat triplet."

Comment: Your 1st quote is ***NOT*** what Wiki says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Tuplet is x notes in the time of y.  A 15:8 group is an example of a tuplet.

A Triplet is a particular type of Tuplet where x=3, y=2.   Three notes in the time of two. Some other common groupings also have a name.

Here's a 7:4 tuplet.

(The notation program Sibelius confuses the issue by labelling the menu where tuplets are constructed as 'Triplets'.)

[image]

Comment: Is it just me, or does Sibelius itself call a septuplet a *sextuplet*?

Comment: No, it calls a septuplet a septuplet.  And a sextuplet a sextuplet.   7-group, 6-group.    What's wrong with my third sentence @Tim?  It's a bar of 4/4.

Comment: There are documents for people already known the subjects.  And there are documents for people like me.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Yes, there's an error in the Sibelius code here. "Creates a sextuplet (7:4)."

Comment: Sheet music very rarely prints the ":4" part, as it's directly obvious from the existence of the half-rest as well as the fact that these are eighth-notes that they have to fit into 2 (quarter-note) beats. Since the rule is "Never make the notes in the run **longer** than default" you can't use sixteenths .

Answer (score 4):

Please re-read Wiki! All *triplets* are *tuplets*, but not all *tuplets* are *triplets*!!

Tuplet is the name given to any non-standard timings within a specified bar. Triplets are one such kind, and are so called because there are three notes played in the time two of the same value are normally played. So, a tad quicker.

Comment: I was reading the wikipedia page over and over, and I didn't even able to understand this even though it seems so obvious now after reading the answers. Even so, I'm still unable to understand how to determine how many notes the tuplets are supposed to replace without reading the entire bar. I'm scared.